# Problem going back from current Fragment back to the replaced Fragment when using NavHostFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have three fragments A, B and C. And I'm using `navHostFragment` container in `MainActivity`. So the application goes from A -> B using kotlin extension function `findNavController().navigate...` and then go from B to C using same function. All works fine till here.

Now in Fragment C, I'm replacing different elements on fragment C using

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager
?.beginTransaction()
?.replace(R.id.list_container, someFragment)
?.addToBackStack("some_frag_id")
?.commit()
```

The `list_container` is replaced with `someFragment`. After this when I press physical back button Fragment C pops out and my app goes to Fragment B while what I expect it to restore replaced `list_container` i.e. whatever was there before replacement.

I'm also overiding this in my `MainActivity`

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val count = supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed()
        //additional code
    }
    else {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is missing here. I have read a lot of solutions on stackoverflow but none worked to my satisfaction. Please guide.

Comment: Is `R.id.list_container` part of Fragment C or part of the Activity's layout?

Comment: @ianhanniballake it is part of Fragment C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding a Fragment to a View within a Fragment, you must always use the `childFragmentManager` - using `activity?.supportFragmentManager` is always the wrong FragmentManager to use in that case.

Besides fixing cases with restoring state (which would not work when using the wrong FragmentManager), this also ensures that the default behavior for dispatching `onBackPressed()` down the FragmentManager hierarchy will work out the box - you should not need any logic at all in `onBackPressed()` to have the pop work correctly.

If you need to intercept the back button in Fragment C, you should follow the [providing custom back documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back) to register an `OnBackPressedDispatcher` - you should not override `onBackPressed()` even in those cases.

Comment: Yeah, that pretty much summed up my problem. However--just to be clear-- in case I want to replace a container that is not part of fragment C I would use 'supportFragmentManager' in that case, right?

Comment: I mean, you'd usually just use the NavController for operating at the higher level. Reaching up to the Activity's FragmentManager is never a good idea.